# Kafka Consumer Reads Inconsistent

Tags: apache-kafka

I have used Spring @KafkaLister for consuming Kafka messages. I am writing a file of 800 messages through Kafka console producer to a topic.

My consumer is inconsistent because it sometimes reads 300 records and sometimes reads 700 and sometimes reads 800.

```
 props.put("zookeeper.connect", a_zookeeper);
 props.put("group.id", a_groupId);
 props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "1000");
 props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
 props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "10000");
```

How can I get consistent reads?

Comment: How many partitions in your topic? Are you sure that the consumer group.id your consumer is using has only one member when you run the test? If you change the group.id and run again do you get all the messages?

Comment: Yeah. This might be a case where there are multiple consumer instances (of the same group.id) without you realizing it and the messages might be distributed amongst them